# Как исключить дублирование?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT 
        od.id as id,
        od.name as branchName,
        SUM(premium) as premSum
FROM Folders f
    inner join DOCS d on d.FOLDERS_ID=f.id
    left join  ogpo_application oa on oa.docs_id=d.DOCS_ID
    INNER join ogpo_dept od on oa.dept_id=od.id and od.type='branch'
Group By od.id, od.name
UNION 
SELECT 
        od1.id as id,
        od1.name  as branchName,
        SUM(pr.InsPremia) as premSum    
FROM      [1cGate].[dbo].[Deals] dl
Left Join [1cGate].[dbo].[Products] pr On pr.DealID = dl.ID
Inner Join FstP.dbo.ogpo_dept od1 On dl.[DeptID]=od1.id and od1.type='branch'
Group By od1.id, od1.name
```

Запрос выводить такой результат:

```
| id | branchName | premSum| 
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | Moscow     | 150000 | 
| 1  | Moscow     | 50000  |
| 3  | Astana     | 16     |
| 4  | Almaty     | 154    |
```

Выборка идет из двух баз.
Как мне избежать от дублирование филиалов? Ожидаю такой результат:

```
| id | branchName | premSum| 
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | Moscow     | 200000 | 
| 3  | Astana     | 16     |
| 4  | Almaty     | 154    |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы объединяете результат группировок двух запросов, а Вам нужно группировать результат объединения двух запросов:

```
select id, branchName, sum(premSum) premSum
from
(
    SELECT 
            od.id as id,
            od.name as branchName,
            premium as premSum
    FROM Folders f
        inner join DOCS d on d.FOLDERS_ID=f.id
        left join  ogpo_application oa on oa.docs_id=d.DOCS_ID
        INNER join ogpo_dept od on oa.dept_id=od.id and od.type='branch'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
            od1.id as id,
            od1.name  as branchName,
            pr.InsPremia as premSum    
    FROM      [1cGate].[dbo].[Deals] dl
    Left Join [1cGate].[dbo].[Products] pr On pr.DealID = dl.ID
    Inner Join FstP.dbo.ogpo_dept od1 On dl.[DeptID]=od1.id and od1.type='branch'
) q
group by id, branchName
```

[Sql fiddle модельный пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/4368)

---

Кстати, использование `union`, а не `union all` приведет к тому, что у Вас будут теряться суммы если они будут дублироваться в Ваших подзапросах.
Т.е. если первый запрос вернет `1, Moscow, 50000` и второй запрос вернет `1, Moscow, 50000`, то в результате получится сумма не 100000, а 50000.

[Sql fiddle пример.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/4369)